# Переход от окна редактирования в окно run IDEintellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Добрый день, подскажите какими сочетаниями клавиш в intellij-idea можно перейти из окна редактирования в окно run для ввода данных с клавиатуры. Обратно из run в окно редактирование можно перейти с помощью Esc.

Comment: alt+4 (10 символов нужно...)

Answer (score 0):

Alt+4.

Другие хоткеи по экранам можно посмотреть в меню View - Tool Windows и в настройках (Keymap).

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!